# Set of Entity beans inside of an Entity bean

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm a beginner and currently I play a little bit with EJB's, Jboss 7.1 and mySQL.

But actually I have a problem.

I want to create the following constellation with entity beans:

1) entity bean with

- a mac address (String)
- a type address (String)
- a si (String)
- a set of data

2) entity bean with

- x values (long)
- y values (double)

That means, the entity bean 1) must have a set of entity beans of 2).

So I implemented 1) as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sensortable")
public class SensorTableBean implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String mac;
private String type;
private String si;
private set<DataBean> data;
...
```

DataBean is an entity bean that includes x and y values.

When I started the server I got a lot of errors

```
[org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000059: Defining hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion=true ignored in HEM
12:34:36,777 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit ....
```

When I remove the line private "set data;" then it works. So most likely the approach with set is completely wrong.

Can you give me a easy example of how you would implement the upper described constellation?

Many thanks!
Have a nice day!

BR

Answer (score 0):

Although the code and log excerpt you posted may not be enough to precisely identify the problem, and assuming that by `private set<DataBean> data;` you actually mean `private Set<DataBean> data;` (note the uppercase "S" in `Set`), you additionally need to annotate your `data` property with [`@OneToMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) and make sure that the `DataBean` class is also mapped properly (with `@Entity`, for example).

More generally, the following are the requisites for JPA Entity classes (from [The Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html)):

> The class must be annotated with the javax.persistence.Entity
>   annotation.
>
> The class must have a public or protected, no-argument constructor.
>   The class may have other constructors.
>
> The class must not be declared final. No methods or persistent
>   instance variables must be declared final.
>
> If an entity instance is passed by value as a detached object, such as
>   through a session bean’s remote business interface, the class must
>   implement the Serializable interface.
>
> Entities may extend both entity and non-entity classes, and non-entity
>   classes may extend entity classes.
>
> Persistent instance variables must be declared private, protected, or
>   package-private and can be accessed directly only by the entity
>   class’s methods. Clients must access the entity’s state through
>   accessor or business methods.

Comment: @OneToMany was the solution =) Many thanks for your help! Now it works fine!! Wish you a nice weekend

Comment: Glad to know it worked. And in that case, you could mark the answer as correct :)